# What do sciptures say about partial fasts in Kaliyuga?

Tags: scripture, kali-yuga, fasting

I have seen almost every people in today's time don't do fasts with shastriya vidhi OR we can say they don't follow full rules of fasts. For example: If we read fasts vidhi about any fasts then we came to know that there is lots of samagri that we need to give 
to Lord i.e. In Satya Narayana fasts there is a [full list of samagri](https://ibb.co/k1HQrL) but I have seen people doing that fasts without full samagri. They just made churma and put bananas in it for and made charnamrit and gave it to Lord. Out of big list of samagri
they gives only few things to Lord.

Another aspect is, when people uses those drinks on even those fasts where drinking is forbidden.
As an another example if we talk about some nirjala fasts i.e. Karwachotha, In this fasts devotee can't drink water. But I heard people saying that if elder will say then we can drink tea. Same goes to Ganesha's nirjala fasts (don't remember name of fast).
In that Ganesha's fast also we can't drink water but heard a lot now days people started to drink and says if any elder say then we can.

So There are two aspects now. One is, when we don't use full list of samagri of fasts, instead we use only few items from samagri list (as shown in Satya Narayana fast example). Second is, when one drinks something in those fasts where drinking is forbidden by saying our elders says so.

Both are little different cases. What I want to know is.. I know this is kali yuga. It's not easy for people to follow full fasts rule. But my question is, what is the result of these partial fasts?

I mean, if people offer only few items from list of samagri then, will we still get full merits of fasting (since it's kaliyuga) OR we will get partial merits OR we will get no merits at all (since we didn't offer full list of samagri to Lord but instead offers only few items from it).

And as per second case, if people of kaliyuga really started to believe that they can drik tea or water on nirjala fasts then will it destory their fasts or it will still remain.

NOTE: I have shows name of fasts just for example purpose. I am not asking question about certain fasts. So consider my mentioned fasts name just as example. This post is not dedicated to particular fast/fasts.

Comment: i have heard from upanyasams (velukkudi, karunakarachar) that partial fast can give at least partial merit, if not full merit, (not zero merit), depending on how much threshold was achieved e.g. ekadashi - not eating during day, but having some light fruits at night - it is noted as almost full fast, since he did try up to his best of abilities. more importantly, if the time was spent in bhagavad-chintanam.

Comment: Fasting is from sunrise to sunset not even a water should touch the lip ! In this Kaliyuga, way to worship supreme Lord is also forgotten. That's why Krishna gave us simple technique to think of him all time and just chant his Maha mantra to go back to him!

Comment: What do scriptures say about partial fasts in Kaliyuga? Is that ur Q? If yes more tags shd be added.

Comment: @rickross Feel free to add more tags :)

Comment: Ok I hv edited see if I hv altered ur Q in any way? @Rishabh